# aggregating Cisco 2960 ports with Cisco 3850

Tags: cisco, trunk, lag

I'm new to networking. I have two switches: Cisco 2960 & Cisco 3850. I want to connect 4 Trunk ports of these switches to each other. Since Cisco 2960 port speed is 1G and Cisco 3850 is 10G, I want to use LAG on both sides, so that I can receive 4G on both sides. However, I encountered this sentence on several resources:

```
All of the aggregated links must:
    use the same data transmission rates
```

So my question is: Since I have 1G on Cisco 2960 side and 10G on Cisco 3850 side, is it possible to use LAG? and should I use static LAG or LCAP?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever LAG mode you use, static or LACP, all interfaces must be linked at the same speed. LACP should be preferred over static since it provides some sanity check.

Since the 2960 series is Fast Ethernet with just two GbE uplinks, you cannot aggregate more than the two uplink ports. More would be overkill anyway, as the downlink capacity wouldn't be able to actually utilize the aggregated uplink.

The 2960**S** series is gigabit throughout and provides more than two GbE ports for LAG. If you're having problems with that series, check the actual link speeds.